# Saving multiple checkbox into localstorage without overwritten

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, checkbox, local-storage

I have a checkbox within a form of which I want it to write to localstorage the status of the checkbox (true/false) upon submission of the form.

So if the user checked the box and clicked submit, the value stored in the localstorage will be "true". However what I don't want is for the data to be overwritten if the user re-opens the app and submit the form again, so for example if the user re-opens the app next time and decide to not check the box on that particular session, the values in the localstorage should be "true, false", and so on.

I think I should use JSON.stringify but not sure exactly how to integrate into here.

Here's my js (I'm using phonegap)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
            document.getElementById("xbutton").addEventListener("click",savecheck,false); }

function savecheck(){
        var checkb = document.getElementById("MedA");
        localStorage.setItem("MedA", checkb.checked);
    }
```

html:

```
<form>
            <div id='medA'>
                <input type="checkbox" id="MedA" name="Med" value="A">Medication A
             </div>
<input id="xbutton" type="button" onClick="savecheck()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now the in the jQuery:

```
var MedA = [100];
localStorage.setItem("index",0);

function savecheck(){

    if($('input[name="chk[]"]:checked')){
        MedA[localStorage.getItem("index")] = $('input[name="chk[]"]').val();
        localStorage.setItem("index",localStorage.getItem("index")+1);
        localStorage.setItem("MedA", JSON.stringify(MedA));
    }


}
```

to get saved check from local storage use

```
function getSavedcheck(){

    var storedMedA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MedA"));

    return storedMedA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load the checkbox state from the localStorage, so then if the users submits the form without modifying the checkbox state, it won't be changed:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.getElementById("xbutton").addEventListener("click",savecheck,false);
  document.getElementById("xbutton").checked = localStorage.getItem("MedA");
}

function savecheck(){
  var checkb = document.getElementById("MedA");
  localStorage.setItem("MedA", checkb.checked);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant. What I mean is that I want the state of the checkbox to save to the localstorage continuously without overwriting anything, so for example the value in localstorage might be "true, false, false, false, true..." etc depending on whether the user checked the box or not on each session